# Why do I get an unexplained whitespace on the right side of my website?

Tags: html, css

When I zoom in my webpage it is showing a white space to the right. I set the width of all the containers to 100%. All the widths inside the container are within 100%. I am not understanding what is causing the overflow to make the white space appear on the right side. Can anyone please find the issue with whats causing this problem. I read all the other answers and they suggest add overflow x:hidden. But I want to know why this strange white space occurs.
Also, since the overflow was occuring, I thought setting all the elements to absolute would solve the problem to get rid of unnecessary paddings. But it is isnt.I thought absolute positioning takes the element out of the flow. But why is this causing overflow. I really need help to find the answer. This bug is keeping me up for hours.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#top-nav{
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  background-image: url("../images/hdr-navi.jpg");
}
#left{
  width: 7%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../images/dashboard-btn.png);
    background-size: 126px 126px;
    background-size: 44px 35px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
#center{
  width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/tab-navi.png);
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    transform: translate(43%, 0);
    background-size: 126px 126px;
    background-size: 496px 44px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
#right{
  width: 6%;
      height: 99%;
      background-image: url(../images/plus-btn.png);
      width: 7%;
      height: 100%;
      float: right;
      background-size: 126px 126px;
      background-size: 44px 35px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-origin: content-box;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
}
#second-nav{
  height: 140px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.container-1{
  height:100%;
  width:75%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;

  }
#id{
  position: absolute;
    margin-top: 21px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Harmattan', sans-serif;
    color: #636363
}
#job{
  position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 39px;
    line-height: 0.5;
    font-family: 'Gudea', sans-serif;
    color: #636363
}
.status-table {
  position: relative;
  width: 78%;
  top: 85px;
  left: 25px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(222,222,222);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.status-table th,td {
  padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.status-table td {
    border-left: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}
.status-table td:first-child {
    border-left: 0px;
}
.status-table th {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.status-table tr:nth-last-child(2) {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #636363;
}
.status-table tr:nth-last-child(1) {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #a2a0a1;
}

.container-2{
  height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/at_t-logo.jpg);
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-size: 126px 126px;
    background-size: 135px 135px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.third-nav{
  height:44px;
  width:100%;
  background-image: url(../images/main-hdr-bg.jpg);
  position: relative;
}
.part1{
  font-size: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: rgb(234,234,234);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.part2 {
  background-image: url(../images/dark-blue-rght.png);
  text-align: center;
  width: 16%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  background-size: 126px 126px;
  background-size: 80px 34px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
#newtask{
  margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.container{
  height:max-content;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #4D4D4D;
}
.mp{
  height:150px;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.mp:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#e4e4e4;

}
.mpleft{
  float:left;
  width:18%;
  height:150px;
}

.mpcenter{
  float: left;
    width: 54%;
    height: 150px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.mpc-heading{
  font-size:20px;
  padding-top: 13px;
}
.mpc-middle{
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 97%;
  line-height: 17px;
}
.attachment{
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 46px;
}
.attachmentimg{
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: 4px;
}
.attachmentp{
  display: inline;
}
.mpright{
  float: left;
    width: 21%;
    height: 150px;
}
.sprite{
  width: 190px;
    height: 56px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sprite td {
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    text-align: right;
    width: 52px; /* Icon width */
    height: 23px;
    font-size: smaller;/* Icon height */
}
.progress {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #9e9e9e;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.progress > span {
  border-right: 1.5px solid white;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.progress.progress-stacked > span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
span:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}
.hazardtype{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.severity{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.mprightarrow{
  float: right;
width: 3%;
height: 150px;
background-image: url(../images/list-arrow.png);
background-size: 31px 28px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-origin: content-box;
background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.foot{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}
.footleft{
  background-image: url(../images/poweredby-remedy-interactive.jpg);
width: 23%;
height: 100%;
background-size: 209px 46px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-origin: content-box;
background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.footright{
  background-image: url(../images/footr-link-rght.jpg);
    height: 33px;
    width: 204px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    border-radius: 7px;
}
#riskasses{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gudea&family=Lexend+Deca&family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Harmattan:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="top-nav">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="second-nav">
    <div class="container-1">
      <p id="id">ID: RA20120328</p>
      <p id="job">Some Job 123</p>
      <table class="status-table">
        <tr>
          <td>RA-STATUS</td>
          <td>DUE DATE</td>
          <td>ASSIGNED TO</td>
          <td>LAST UPDATED</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Open-Draft</td>
          <td>04/20/2012</td>
          <td>John Doe(for you)</td>
          <td>03/28/2012 | By: John Doe</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container-2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="third-nav">
    <div class="part1">
      <p>TASKS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="part2">
      <p id="newtask">+ New Task</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

  <div class="mp">
    <div class="mpleft"  style="background-image: url(./images/img-thumb.jpg);background-size: 138px 133px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;background-origin: content-box;background-position: 50% 50%; ">
    </div>
    <div class="mpcenter" id="mpcenter1">
      <p class="mpc-heading">This is Some Task</p>
      <p class="mpc-middle">In sit amet augue vitae metus pharetra ornare. Sed non dapibus magna. Nulla vitae urna nisl. Cras feugiat luctus maximus.Donec tristique elit vel sem blandit, a bibendum tellus aliquet. Vestibulum id mauris in velit volutpat dignissim. Quisque facilisis urna tempus, pellentesque elit eget, convallis risus. Mauris.</p>

      <div class="attachment">
        <img  class="attachmentimg"src="./images/attachment.png" alt="">
        <p class="attachmentp">2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mpright">
      <p class="hazardtype">HAZARD TYPE</p>
      <table class="sprite" >
        <tr>
          <td class="a" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position: 4px 2px;  ">2</td>
          <td class="b" style=" background: url(./images/icon-deactive.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px 2px; color: #d0d0d0;">0</td>
          <td class="c" style=" background: url(./images/icon-deactive.png) no-repeat;  background-position:-122px 2px; color: #d0d0d0;">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="d" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat;   background-position:4px -26px;">2</td>
          <td class="e" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px -26px;">15</td>
          <td class="f" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-122px -26px;">7</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p class="severity">SEVERITY</p>
      <div class="progress progress-stacked">
        <span style="width: 33%; background: url(./images/green-color.jpg);" class="bg-green">25</span>
        <span style="width: 33%;  background: url(./images/orange-color.jpg);" class="bg-yellow">14</span>
        <span style="width: 0%; background: url(./images/red-color.jpg);" class="bg-red"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mprightarrow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mp">
    <div class="mpleft"  style="background-image: url(./images/img-thumb2.jpg);background-size: 138px 133px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;background-origin: content-box;background-position: 50% 50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="mpcenter" id="mpcenter2">
      <p class="mpc-heading">Mixing Chemical X</p>
      <p class="mpc-middle">In sit amet augue vitae metus pharetra ornare. Sed non dapibus magna. Nulla vitae urna nisl. Cras feugiat luctus maximus.Donec tristique elit vel sem blandit, a bibendum tellus aliquet. Vestibulum id mauris in velit volutpat dignissim. Quisque facilisis urna tempus, pellentesque elit eget, convallis risus. Mauris.</p>
      <div class="attachment">
        <img  class="attachmentimg"src="./images/attachment.png" alt="">
        <p class="attachmentp">2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mpright">
      <p class="hazardtype">HAZARD TYPE</p>
      <table class="sprite" >
        <tr>
          <td class="a" style=" background: url(./images/icon-deactive.png) no-repeat; background-position: 4px 2px; color: #d0d0d0;">0</td>
          <td class="b" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px 2px;">15</td>
          <td class="c" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat;  background-position:-122px 2px;">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="d" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat;   background-position:4px -26px;">2</td>
          <td class="e" style=" background: url(./images/icon-deactive.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px -26px; color: #d0d0d0;">0</td>
          <td class="f" style=" background: url(./images/icon-deactive.png) no-repeat; background-position:-122px -26px; color: #d0d0d0;">0</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p class="severity">SEVERITY</p>
      <div class="progress progress-stacked">
        <span style="width: 32.7%; background: url(./images/green-color.jpg);" class="bg-green">20</span>
        <span style="width: 33%;  background: url(./images/orange-color.jpg);" class="bg-yellow">02</span>
        <span style="width: 32.7%; background: url(./images/red-color.jpg);" class="bg-red">03</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mprightarrow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mp">
    <div class="mpleft" style="background-image: url(./images/img-thumb3.jpg);background-size: 138px 133px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;background-origin: content-box;background-position: 50% 50%;" ></div>
    <div class="mpcenter" id="mpcenter3">
      <p class="mpc-heading">Climbing Large Rocks</p>
      <p class="mpc-middle">In sit amet augue vitae metus pharetra ornare. Sed non dapibus magna. Nulla vitae urna nisl. Cras feugiat luctus maximus.Donec tristique elit vel sem blandit, a bibendum tellus aliquet. Vestibulum id mauris in velit volutpat dignissim. Quisque facilisis urna tempus, pellentesque elit eget, convallis risus. Mauris.</p>
      <div class="attachment">
        <img  class="attachmentimg"src="./images/attachment.png" alt="">
        <p class="attachmentp">2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mpright">
      <p class="hazardtype">HAZARD TYPE</p>
      <table class="sprite" >
        <tr>
          <td class="a" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position: 4px 2px;  ">2</td>
          <td class="b" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px 2px; ">15</td>
          <td class="c" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat;  background-position:-122px 2px; ">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="d" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat;   background-position:4px -26px;">2</td>
          <td class="e" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px -26px;">15</td>
          <td class="f" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-122px -26px;">7</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p class="severity">SEVERITY</p>
      <div class="progress progress-stacked">
        <span style="width: 32.7%; background: url(./images/green-color.jpg);" class="bg-green">20</span>
        <span style="width: 33%;  background: url(./images/orange-color.jpg);" class="bg-yellow">02</span>
        <span style="width: 32.7%; background: url(./images/red-color.jpg);" class="bg-red">03</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mprightarrow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mp">
    <div class="mpleft" style="background-image: url(./images/img-thumb.jpg);background-size: 138px 133px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;background-origin: content-box;background-position: 50% 50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="mpcenter" >
      <p class="mpc-heading">Lifting Heavy Boxes</p>
      <p class="mpc-middle">In sit amet augue vitae metus pharetra ornare. Sed non dapibus magna. Nulla vitae urna nisl. Cras feugiat luctus maximus.Donec tristique elit vel sem blandit, a bibendum tellus aliquet. Vestibulum id mauris in velit volutpat dignissim. Quisque facilisis urna tempus, pellentesque elit eget, convallis risus. Mauris.</p>
      <div class="attachment">
        <img  class="attachmentimg"src="./images/attachment.png" alt="">
        <p class="attachmentp">2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mpright">
      <p class="hazardtype">HAZARD TYPE</p>
      <table class="sprite" >
        <tr>
          <td class="a" style=" background: url(./images/icon-deactive.png) no-repeat; background-position: 4px 2px; color: #d0d0d0;">0</td>
          <td class="b" style=" background: url(./images/icon-deactive.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px 2px; color: #d0d0d0;">0</td>
          <td class="c" style=" background: url(./images/icon-deactive.png) no-repeat;  background-position:-122px 2px; color: #d0d0d0;">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="d" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat;   background-position:4px -26px;">2</td>
          <td class="e" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px -26px;">15</td>
          <td class="f" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-122px -26px;">7</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p class="severity">SEVERITY</p>
      <div class="progress progress-stacked">
        <span style="width: 33%; background: url(./images/green-color.jpg);" class="bg-green">20</span>
        <span style="width: 0%;  background: url(./images/orange-color.jpg);" class="bg-yellow"></span>
        <span style="width: 0%; background: url(./images/red-color.jpg);" class="bg-red"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mprightarrow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mp">
    <div class="mpleft" style="background-image: url(./images/img-thumb4.jpg);background-size: 138px 133px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;background-origin: content-box;background-position: 50% 50%;">

    </div>
    <div class="mpcenter">
      <p class="mpc-heading">Pouring Hot Coffee</p>
      <p class="mpc-middle">In sit amet augue vitae metus pharetra ornare. Sed non dapibus magna. Nulla vitae urna nisl. Cras feugiat luctus maximus.Donec tristique elit vel sem blandit, a bibendum tellus aliquet. Vestibulum id mauris in velit volutpat dignissim. Quisque facilisis urna tempus, pellentesque elit eget, convallis risus. Mauris.</p>
      <div class="attachment">
        <img  class="attachmentimg"src="./images/attachment.png" alt="">
        <p class="attachmentp">2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mpright">
      <p class="hazardtype">HAZARD TYPE</p>
      <table class="sprite" >
        <tr>
          <td class="a" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position: 4px 2px;  ">2</td>
          <td class="b" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px 2px; ">15</td>
          <td class="c" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat;  background-position:-122px 2px; ">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="d" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat;   background-position:4px -26px;">2</td>
          <td class="e" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-56px -26px;">15</td>
          <td class="f" style=" background: url(./images/icon-item.png) no-repeat; background-position:-122px -26px;">7</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p class="severity">SEVERITY</p>
      <div class="progress progress-stacked">
        <span style="width: 30%; background: url(./images/green-color.jpg);" class="bg-green">20</span>
        <span style="width: 30%;  background: url(./images/orange-color.jpg);" class="bg-yellow">14</span>
        <span style="width: 30%; background: url(./images/red-color.jpg);" class="bg-red">09</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="mprightarrow"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="foot">
<div class="footleft"></div>
<div class="footright">
  <p id="riskasses">Submit Risk Assessment for Approval</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, the space is not showing here when I run the snippet. But when I open in chrome and zoom, the space appears on the right side.

Comment: You asked, then closed, the [same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944845/why-is-there-a-unexplained-white-space-on-the-right-side-on-my-website).

Comment: @Mitya Yes I thought I framed the question in a wrong way. So I rephrased it.

Comment: To rephrase your question, instead of deleting it, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) it.